# Hello World using mod_wsgi, Internal error, misconfiguration

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, mod-wsgi

I'm on Windows, and am trying to invoke mod_wsgi on an Apache server. I located mod_wsgi.so in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/` and I have a directory called MyApp - `/home/danu_bg/public_html/MyApp` .

Within this directory I have `application.wsgi`

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK' 
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

And the `.htaccess` configuration file is

```
<Directory /home/danu_bg/public_html/MyApp>
WSGIScriptAlias /home/danu_bg/public_html/MyApp/application.wsgi
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I don't think I can access the main configuration file, `httpd.config` when I look in `/usr/lib/apache2/build` I see `config.nice` but don't see `httpd.config`

I'm using WinSCP to connect to the server, I do not have shell access.
When I go to the URL, I get this error

```
 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request
```

Comment: You can't put Directory/WSGIScriptAlias inside of a .htaccess file. It is not enough for the mod_wsgi.so to be on the system, Apache has to be configured to load it. You really need to find out from the host provider whether Apache is even configured to load mod_wsgi. If it is a shared system, they shouldn't be allowing you to use mod_wsgi from a .htaccess file as it is a security risk to do so unless they have taken special action to configure mod_wsgi to isolate your application to its own process.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the page https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives

I see the following syntax for the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /name /web/wsgi-scripts/name
```

So the directive takes two arguments: the URI and the wsgi script. In your case that might be something like:

WSGIScriptAlias /app /public_html/MyApp/application.wsgi

to expose your application under the /app URL.

Comment: Hi Freek, I've edited the answer to include the full path that I've used

Answer (score -1):

maybe its the a form of indentation error present when
a newtyper tries to type something:  ******edit: is i see right
there it has the --spaces: --type-those-backwards:

-> now im getting 404 : https://pastebin.com/LgvyNWVX
fix with vhost file default_vhost_wsgi : the reason you get 503
or 404 is due to improper aligning using wsgi the same way you think
python is is it has to be aligned all at the top:

--zeroing: ok RIGHT RIGHT YOU WONT FIND theyre like were of a crossing - convenient store make it jcpennies OK RIGHT RIGHT: and how theyre using the same thing to differ like the data being sent on this tab received: <- between a school and : find the root of target co oh but im just learning:will POP - OPEN THIS ARRAY software BUTTON ARRAY;
means theyre all like but was i doing:

- and then save it as a file is from MASM/NASA: [p[[pedp[entheglypbuttons

1.: set up virtual host on port 8080: is has to specify this in the url: as a separate vhost file like 00_default_vhost_wsgi: https://pastebin.com/CMdgj4Ne : and its ***WORKING:

```
<script crossorigin='anonymous'> 
xhr.open('POST', 'localhost:8080', true)
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.responseType = "text";
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*'),
                    ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'),
                    ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET');
xhr.send(view.buffer.string);
```

...if you want to fix it: https://pastebin.com/HEyscL7T
WSGIScriptAlias /python_helloworld_wsgi "/var/www/localhost/wsgi-scripts/python_helloworld.wsgi"

<Directory "/var/www/localhost/wsgi-scripts">
Options ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
Require all granted

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

https://pastebin.com/exSCDPY7
OK: so Nothing about the Application: The HEADERS between
the SERVER and SERVER meaning if your Running XAMPP
--including --python: the HEAdERS have to #INCLUDE this SPECIFICALLY:
and match in the HTML file your trying to use :

```
 [('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
                ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'),
                ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET'),
                ('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

: HTML FILE: 
    <script Access-Control-Allow-Origin="anonymous *">
```

1. const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('GET', 'localhost:8080',
   true); xhr.withCredentials = true; xhr.responseType = "text";
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
   ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*'),
   ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'),
   ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET'); xhr.send(null); xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { if
   (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { const data =
   xhr.response; console.log(data); } else { console.log('Error:
   ${xhr.status}'); } } xhr.open('POST', 'localhost:8080', true)
   xhr.withCredentials = true; xhr.responseType = "text";
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
   ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*'),
   ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'),
   ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET'); xhr.send(view.buffer.string); xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { const data =
   xhr.response; console.log(xhr.response); } else {
   console.log('Error:    ${xhr.status}'); } }

Comment: Please try to improve the formatting and content of your answer. This might help: [about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)